# How can I reference elements between different parts of the documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Say I have a normal documentation part and additionally a glossar, both build in the same sphinx project.

Is there a way to link a word with let's say a headline on another page without using a normal static link?

If there is no other way than a static link, is there a possibility to introduce IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a link to any spot in your project using [cross references](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#ref-role). For example:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```